# How to import photos from dropbox into cordova app?

Tags: cordova, extjs, dropbox, inappbrowser

I am developing an app in sencha touch cordova and I am able to open dropbox using in app browser

```
window.open('http://www.dropbox.com/', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

but after opening dropbox I want to import image .

Comment: Have you looked at the [Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js)? Does it meet your needs?

Comment: thanks for reply @smarx . the dropbox chooser working in safari browser. but when i run the application in windows phone cordova app an alert message displayed    :   Your browser does not support the dropbox chooser ? can you please give any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Which version of Windows Phone? I believe it should work on Windows Phone 8.1 but not earlier versions. If the Chooser isn't an option for you, you can integrate via the Core API.

Comment: thanks for reply @smarx i am working on Windows Phone 8.1 and when i click on the choose from dropbox alert message displayed.   Your browser does not support the dropbox chooser.

Comment: @smarx i have used dropbox core api. but i am getting this error missing redirect_uri(required when "response_type" is "token")

Comment: Does the Chooser work on your phone if you try the sample at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js? If so, perhaps the in-app browser used by Cordova is a different version. You could check that via http://whatsmyuseragent.com/.

Comment: For the Core API, are you in fact missing the redirect URI? :-) You may want to look at https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/06/using-dropbox-datastores-in-a-cordova-app/, which is for the Datastore API, but the same sort of thing should work for https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js.

Comment: @smarx i think you are not understanding my problem. let me explain it. I have created an app using sencha touch and cordova 3.4 . In my app i want to add a functionality to choose image from dropbox.

Comment: @smarx         here is the link to the problem with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712900/import-photos-from-dropbox-into-cordova-app

Comment: @smarx can you tell me is there any plugin for using dropbox chooser in cordova for blackberry10 mobile